# Ehler's Smoothing Filter code in pine script

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to code Ehler's smoothing filter in pine script version 5. The code is as follows -

```
PI=3.14159265359
EhlersSuperSmootherFilter(price, lower) =>
    a1 = math.exp(-PI * math.sqrt(2) / lower)
    coeff2 = 2 * a1 * math.cos(math.sqrt(2) * PI / lower)
    coeff3 = - math.pow(a1,2)
    coeff1 = 1 - coeff2 - coeff3
    filt = coeff1 * (price + nz(price[1])) / 2 + coeff2 * nz(filt[1]) + coeff3 * nz(filt[2]) 
    filt
```

This code is giving me the following error -

> Undeclared identifier 'filt'

Please help me to fix this. Thanks for your time. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to declare the filt variable like below before using it like filt[1] etc

```
PI=3.14159265359
EhlersSuperSmootherFilter(price, lower) =>
    var filt=0.0
    a1 = math.exp(-PI * math.sqrt(2) / lower)
    coeff2 = 2 * a1 * math.cos(math.sqrt(2) * PI / lower)
    coeff3 = - math.pow(a1,2)
    coeff1 = 1 - coeff2 - coeff3
    filt := coeff1 * (price + nz(price[1])) / 2 + coeff2 * nz(filt[1]) + coeff3 * nz(filt[2])
```

Comment: I want to add it on different oscillators with an apply on off option. How can I do that? What should be the code to do so?

Comment: you can add a if condition before calling this function. if the apply condition is true then call this function else use the price directly

Comment: `applySmoothing=input.bool(defval=false, title="Smooth IMI")

imi=applySmoothing ? EhlersSuperSmootherFilter(100*(upt/(upt+dnt)), lowBand) : 100*(upt/(upt+dnt))`

When I am coding this in pine script version 5 it is not working. How can I fix this